# Find direct hierarchical parents of a leaf node in data.tree package in R

Tags: r, tree

I am trying to create a sub tree from a data tree and need to perform further operations on the sub tree.

```
data(acme)
print(acme)

Acme Inc.                       
2   ¦--Accounting                  
3   ¦   ¦--New Software            
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards

5  ¦--  Research                    
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        
7   ¦   °--New Labs                
8 |--IT                          
9         |--Outsource               
10       ¦--Go agile                
11       °--Switch to R
```

Now I want to create a sub tree corresponding to the leaf node specified in the name variable below:

```
name<-"New Labs"
```

Following code gives me the required sub tree:

```
subtree<-(FindNode(acme, name)$parent)$parent
print (subtree)

Acme Inc.       
2  °--Research    
3      °--New Labs
```

But I need a code which doesn't require multiple repetition of "$parent" & gives all the parent till the tree root.

Any help on this would be really appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to `Prune` the initial tree to a new tree.

We can find the path of any `Node` with the `path` propriety, and then `Prune()` the tree Traversing the tree and keeping only the nodes matching the path.

Because `Prune()` overwrite the initial tree, we should probably `Clone()` it first.

```r
library(data.tree)
data("acme")

acme
#>                           levelName
#> 1  Acme Inc.                       
#> 2   ¦--Accounting                  
#> 3   ¦   ¦--New Software            
#> 4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards
#> 5   ¦--Research                    
#> 6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        
#> 7   ¦   °--New Labs                
#> 8   °--IT                          
#> 9       ¦--Outsource               
#> 10      ¦--Go agile                
#> 11      °--Switch to R

extract_subtree <- function(tree, node_name) {
  new_tree <- Clone(tree)
  initial_node <- FindNode(new_tree, node_name)
  initial_node$path
  Prune(new_tree, prunFun = function(N) N$name %in% initial_node$path)
  return(new_tree)
}

pruned_acme <- extract_subtree(acme, 'New Labs')

pruned_acme
#>          levelName
#> 1 Acme Inc.       
#> 2  °--Research    
#> 3      °--New Labs


acme
#>                           levelName
#> 1  Acme Inc.                       
#> 2   ¦--Accounting                  
#> 3   ¦   ¦--New Software            
#> 4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards
#> 5   ¦--Research                    
#> 6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        
#> 7   ¦   °--New Labs                
#> 8   °--IT                          
#> 9       ¦--Outsource               
#> 10      ¦--Go agile                
#> 11      °--Switch to R
```

Created on 2018-05-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot @GGamba !